# I Have A Tabbed Web Browser In VB And I Want To Allow New Tabs To Open In My Browser Instead of IE

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, tabs

I am designing the 8th update to my tabbed vb web browser (found at swordfish.savershot.net)in VB Express 08 and I'm having trouble with something. Whenever a webpage wants to open a link in a new tab (aka: Google Drive New Document), Internet Explorer turns on and runs the tab through them. I understand how it happens, because VB.NET by default uses IE as their Web Browsing core. However, I do not like it and I would love to be able to set those links to either open in a new tab in my browser or a new window in my browser. I have found a way to cancel the operation altogether but that's not very user friendly and I'd love to get my browser to a level where I can actually use it comfortably without annoying issues occurring. Thanks for the help.